# shared_xaxis with plotly, but can I still display the axis on each plot?

Tags: python, plotly, axis-labels

if you share the x_axis between 2 plots, they will get aligned, as expected.

however, the axis is displayed only once, on a single plot and not on both anymore.

Is it possible to display the axis on each plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Plotly Express, there is no way to do this at the moment. If you're using the underlying `make_subplots` method, however, this is the default behaviour: https://plot.ly/python/subplots/

Comment: This is no longer the case. Just see the https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#subplots-with-shared-xaxes documentation. Only one the bottom x-axis is visible. An other subtle detail is that if the bottom plot don't have any data the axis/tick markers become messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate tick marks on each subplot after using `shared_xaxes=True`

Simply do the following to re-enable them one-by-one manually:

```
figure.update_layout(xaxis_showticklabels=True)
figure.update_layout(xaxis2_showticklabels=True)
...
```